# Huffman Tree Inserting/Retrieving values incorrectly

Tags: c++, character-encoding, binary, huffman-code

In my c++ implementation of Huffman encoding and decoding, I keep receiving weird output when attempting to decode and output the result. For example, given the input:

11 00001 01 11 101 01 11 1001 01 101 1000 01 00000 0011 00101 01 11 101 01 11 1001 01 00100 00011 01 101 1000 01 00010 0011

It should, in theory, decode to "if it is to be, it is up to me," but instead, I receive "if,isefbe,,ismfttofp"

There are other test cases that return equally odd results, but I don't think the specific results are of use, other than the fact that I'm pretty sure my implementation of inserting into the Huffman Tree is incorrect somehow.

Notably, though, none of the results I received ever included any spaces.

The code for my Huffman Tree is

```
void huffmanTree(huffmanNode *n, string prefix, char letter) {
    if (prefix.length() == 0) {
        n->character = letter;
    }
    if (prefix[0] == '0') {
        if (n->left == NULL) {
            n->left = new huffmanNode(0, '\0');
        }
        huffmanTree(n->left, prefix.substr(1, prefix.length()-1), letter);
    } else if (prefix[0] == '1') {
        if (n->right == NULL) {
            n->right = new huffmanNode(0, '\0');
        }
        huffmanTree(n->right, prefix.substr(1, prefix.length()-1), letter);
    }
}
```

It's also possible that the problem lies in my traversal, which is:

```
char buffer[256];
huffmanNode *n = new huffmanNode(0, '\0');

while (true) {
    char first = file.get();
    if ((first == '\n') || (first == '\r')) {
        continue;
    }
    
    char second = file.get();
    if ((first == '-') && (second == '-')) {
        file.getline(buffer, 255, '\n');
        break;
    }
    file.getline(buffer, 255, '\n');
        
    string prefixCode = string(buffer);
    huffmanTree(n,prefixCode,first);
}
    
huffmanNode *n1 = n;
char bit;
    
while ((bit = file.get()) != '-') {
    if ((bit != '0') && (bit != '1')) {
        continue;
    }
    if (n1->left != NULL && bit == '0') {
        n1 = n1->left;
    }
    if (n1->right != NULL && bit == '1') {
        n1 = n1->right;
    }
    if (n1->left == NULL && n1->right == NULL) {
        cout << n1->getChar();
        n1 = n;
    }
}
```

Is there some glaringly obvious thing causing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Your tree build and decode code looks fine. Perhaps there is something wrong with the file you are reading the codes and symbols from, or with the code to read it.

Comment: Your `substr` will work, but you don't need the second argument. The default is to go to the end.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you need to add two error checks in your decoder. First is if your Huffman code is not complete, and you get data that sends you down a NULL branch. You need to detect that and report invalid data. Second, at the end of your loop, you need to check that `n1 == n`. If not, then the data ended in the middle of a code that was not decoded.